# Bash script to recognise archive format and extract files from archives not working

Tags: bash, unix

The following Bash script is supposed to recognise archives and unpack them. Archives are given as arguments for the script. However, the script always tries to unzip any file I provide, independently on the archive type.

How the script works - (at least in the console) it checks the description of the file by using the file command, then the output is piped to grep which is looking for a specific word in the description (the name of the archive type), then it counts occurrences of this word. Only the count is higher than zero a specific extraction command is being executed. I mean, it should work as I described, but it does not.

I tried `test -lt`, I tried changing parentheses into brackets, I tried adding semicolons, but whatever I do I always receive error messages. The code I provide below works without error messages, but instead of using appropriate tar extraction commands, it keeps using unzip, which obviously does not work with archives which require other programs.

```
#!/bin/bash
zero=0
for plik in $@; do
     if ( file $plik | grep 'zip' | wc -l);
          then 
            unzip $plik
          elif ( file $plik | grep 'tar' | wc -l);
          then 
            tar -xvjf $plik
          elif ( file $plik | grep 'bzip2' | wc -l );
          then 
            tar -xvjf $plik
          elif ( file $plik | grep 'gzip' | wc -l );
          then 
             tar -xvzf $plik
          elif ( file $plik | grep '7-zip' | wc -l ); 
          then 
              7z x $plik
          else
            case $plik in
               *.tar.bz2) tar -xvjf $plik ;;
               *.bz2)     tar -xvjf $plik ;;
               *.tar.gz)  tar -xvzf $plik ;;
               *.tgz)     tar -xvzf $plik ;;
               *.gz)      gunzip $plik ;;
               *.zip)     unzip $plik ;;
               *.7z)      7z x $plik ;;
               *)         echo "I cannot unpack it";
            esac;
     fi
do
```

ne

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error-messages ? Which one do you get?

Comment: elf magic numbers <3

Comment: Avoid using sub-shells `( )` when not needed. You can remove all `( )`

Comment: Are you aware of `tar -a` (autodetect compression type)?

Comment: As an aside, you should quote your variable expansions - `"$@"` and `"$plik"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing

```
file $plik | grep 'zip' | wc -l
```

with

```
file "$plik" | grep 'zip'
```

The exit code of grep tells you whether there is at least one matching line or not. If you pipe this to `wc -l` you will always get a successful result, because the string '0' represents success.

Of course you have to replace all occurences of `| wc -l`.

Comment: Using `-q` might be good too. As would only running `file` once instead of N times.

Comment: Also, technically, the return code of `grep` tells you whether there was any output or not. Not if there were any matching lines (think about `-v`).

Comment: Actually, my comment should have been on the question - done.

Answer (score 2):

If you can install [dtrx](https://github.com/moonpyk/dtrx) on your system, you should use it. It's build for your problem and available through the package manager on most systems.

Otherwise, this would be my proposal:

```
#!/bin/bash

extract() {
    for plik in "$@"; do
        tar -xvaf "$plik" 2>/dev/null && 
            return 0
        case $(file "$plik") in
            *bzip2*)    bzip2 -dk "$plik"        ;;
            *gzip*)     gunzip "$plik"           ;;
            *'7-zip'*)  7z x "$plik"             ;;
            *zip*)                               ;&
            *Zip*)      unzip "$plik"            ;;
            *xz*)                                ;&
            *XZ*)       unxz  "$plik"            ;;
            *)          1>&2 echo "Unknown archive '$plik'"; return 1 ;;
        esac
    done
}

extract archive1 archive2 # ...
```

Some notes:

- Tries `tar`'s auto-detect feature first

If that fails

- Uses shell built-ins and only runs `file` once per archive
- Quoting the filename guards against a number of weird characters that might be in a file name (e.g. spaces).
- IMHO, there is no point in detecting an archive by extension since they can have a wrong name one

Answer (score 0):

Actually this script needs another modification (except for the removal of the wc -l part).

If a compressed file is for example in gzip format, then it would match the first if clause ( `file $plik | grep 'zip'` ), and it would fail to uncompress the gzipped file.

I 've modified the script to match the simple zip's at the last elif, and the script works as expected.